# Crystal Report get value for element with is equal to other field

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a problem that I want to solve.

I have two tables, **AINVDET** and **STOCK**

On report I have got fields from **AINVDET**
*Field1 Field2 Field999*

*Field999* is created from Formula Field

> ToText(Field1)+ToText(Field2)

I want to create formula, that will match **Field999** with **part** from Table **STOCK**, and if found match, print field **cost_average** from table **STOCK** for **Field999** = **part**

---

I have tried

> **if** Field999 = stock.part **then** stock.cost_average **else** 0

I have also try with SELECT, FROM, WHERE, but it doesn't look to work in Formula fields in Crystal Reports. Also I have try to put this in SQL Expression Fields, but with an error.

Any help?

Comment: Ideally, this should be fixed in the database so that you have an actual foreign key. If you can't do that, you'll have to create a SQL Command and join the two tables manually (how are they joined currently, by the way?)

Comment: Why dont you just add the table Stock to the report and join it with any of the other tables. That would make it easier.

Comment: In order to answer your question you need to tell us how you are linnking the tables `AINVDET and STOCK`